# LaTeX: cite with [ ] argument in caption

Tags: arguments, latex, figure, caption

I need the source of images listed in the "list of figures". 
To do this I want to cite inside the caption argument:

This works:

```
\caption[Plan,\protect\cite{damluji1992}]{Plan}
```

This works too but i need it in the caption argument like in the next example:

```
\cite[p.156]{damluji1992}
```

I need this which doesn't work:

```
\caption[Plan,\protect\cite[p.156]{damluji1992}]{Plan}
```

it gives me the error "Argument of \HAR@dcite has an extra }."
In the *.lof file the corresponding line looks like this:

```
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {2}{\ignorespaces Plan, \cite [S.156}}{5}{figure.caption.4}
```

-> the cite argument in { } is missing!

Without the cite argument in [ ] it looks like this:

```
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {2}{\ignorespaces Plan, \cite {damluji1992}}}{5}{figure.caption.4}
```

Comment: Please consider http://tex.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled on this page with the same question and then found the answer at http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=6225

The solution: put curly braces around the cite command:

```
{\cite[Theorem~2]{mEtAl}}
```

The reason this is necessary is that you have an optional [] argument inside another optional [] argument.

Answer (score 0):

In preamble:

```
\usepackage{caption}[2011/11/10]

\newcommand{\figsource}[1]{%
  \addtocounter{figure}{-1}
  \captionlistentry{source: #1}
 }
```

in document:

```
\begin{figure} 
  \includegraphics...
  \caption{whatever}
  \figsource{whatever-source}
\end{figure}
```

produces:

> List of Figures
>
> 1.1 whatever . . . . . . . . 29
>
> 1.1 whatever-source: . . . . 29